# Laravel query builder subquery separate tables

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

How do I write this in *Laravel Query Builder*:

- I have a *users* table that has one *Customer* with column `'phone'`.
- a *customers* table that belongs to *User* on `'user_id'` with column `'mobile`'.

I would like to find any customer id that with a phone number what either 'phone' or 'mobile'.  Something like this:

```
select id 
from customers 
where mobile = '5555555555' or 
user_id = (select id 
           from users 
           where phone = '5555555555')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what I need:

```
$customers = DB::table('customers')
    ->whereIn('user_id',  function ($query) use ($phoneNumber) {
        $query->select('id')
              ->from('users')
              ->where('users.phone', $phoneNumber);
    })
    ->orWhere('mobile', $phoneNumber)
    ->pluck('id');
```